# MySQL join json

Tags: mysql, json

To avoid using temporary tables, I hoped to store some data as a json array within a variable and join on it. The data looks something like this:

```
[
  {
    "CarID": "9",
    "Tank": "11.4",
    "Distance": "120",
    "From": "Brussels",
    "To": "Bruges"
  },
  {
    "CarID": "22",
    "Tank": "15.9",
    "Distance": "70",
    "From": "Eupen",
    "To": "Cologne"
  }
]
```

I would like to set a variable in mysql to that value and be able to do something like the following:

```
SELECT
    (
        Cars.Consumption
        * JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_something('???','$.Distance'))
    ) - JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_something('???','$.Tank')) AS neededRefuel
FROM    Cars
WHERE   JSON_SEARCH(
            @myJson,
            'one',
            CAST(Cars.CarID AS JSON),
            NULL,
            '$[*].CarID'
        ) IS NOT NULL
```

This is just a simplified example.
Apparently json values as integer are not easy to detect in mysql, so I set quotes.

I wanted to use this kind of filter within a view, so temporary tables are not really an option.

Using MySQL 8.0.11

Comment: I am not very sure, but isn't this a bad idea, for large data sets. No indices ? can be used for your joins.

Comment: What would you recommend when you have to select like 3 cars, also pass one additional parameter to each and all of that within a huge query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just humbled upon [JSON_TABLE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html) and it seems to do exactly what I want :)

Comment: How humiliating